# Boolean method 'Blackjack' for arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to write a boolean method that checks if  a sum of integers in an array equals 21. Here's the code:

```
def twenty_one? (*arr) 
  arr.inject(0){|sum,x| sum + x }
  arr.eql? (21)
end
```

But if I check

```
puts twenty_one?(19, 2)
```

it returns `false`, even though I tried some others too. What am I missing in this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Enumrable#inject` does not transform array to number. You check equality of array and number, which always returns `false`. According to your logic, you should compare the result of `inject` with number:

```
def twenty_one? (*arr) 
  sum = arr.inject(0) { |sum,x| sum + x }
  sum.eql?(21)
end

twenty_one?(19, 2)
#=> true
```

Or you can use `reduce`:

```
def twenty_one?(*arr) 
  arr.reduce(:+) == 21
end
```

Or you can do it shorter by using ActiveSupport `Enumerable#sum`:

```
def twenty_one?(*arr) 
  arr.sum == 21
end
```

Comment: Using `eql?` is really unusual. Normally `==` is expected.

Comment: [`Enumerable#sum`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) is a Rails / ActiveSupport method.

Answer (score 3):

You inject sum which wil hold the total at the end of the array but the scope is lost once out of the codeblock, you have to assign this to a variable like Ilya shows or use this shorter version which compares this result to 21 straight away.

```
def twenty_one? (*arr) 
  arr.inject(:+) == 21
end
```

See [this](http://renderedtext.com/blog/2016/02/18/inject-is-a-fundamental-building-block/) blog for a detailed explanation of inject and the shothand :+

Comment: You're the first to answer remembering that `inject` takes the first element in the array as a seed if no argument is given, that's much cleaner.

Comment: @peter Yeah, I just tested that myself as I was thinking for a moment about how *comparing* in the context of `sort_by` causes problems, but `==` is cool with it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Probably should after forgetting something like that!

Comment: Although `==` works in this case, I'd use `inject(0, :+)` to ensure an integer result.